# BS4 ebay scraper prints text including html code

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am trying to run a BS4 ebay scraper based on a video on youtube by some russian guy. I quite new to this style of coding a scraper, ive only used selenium so far, but wanted to try something new and faster which could be deployed once on a server so i would be able to get data i scrape into my phone for example when im not at home. My goal is to print out text from h3 objects i parse but the output prints this: ("<h 3 class="s-item__title">Samsung NP9004D 900X Intel i5-3317U / 4GB RAM / 13,3 Zoll</h 3>") instead of this (Samsung NP9004D 900X Intel i5-3317U / 4GB RAM / 13,3 Zoll)
Could anyone please explain what im doing wrong? Thank you very much!
PS: If anyone knows a better way of creating an ebay specific scraper, help would be appreciated! Like automating stuff or creating a custom API...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print("Server responded:", response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    return soup


def get_detail_data(soup):
    listing = soup.find("div", {"class": "s-item__wrapper clearfix"})
    name = soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "s-item__title"}, text=True)
    print(name)






def main():
    url = "https://www.ebay.de/b/Laptops-Notebooks/175672/bn_1618754?LH_ItemCondition=7000&mag=1&rt=nc&_sop=1"
    get_page(url)
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: so are you not able to fetch `name` ??

Comment: Oh the post kinda reedited itself, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_detail_data(soup):
    listing = soup.find("div", {"class": "s-item__wrapper clearfix"})
    names = soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "s-item__title"})
    for name in names:
        if chr(9650) in str(name):
            print(name.text.strip().replace(chr(9650), ''))
        else:
            print(name.text.strip())
```

Comment: Yes this is also a good answer, and it prints it out a bit nicer. Thanks man, ill try to make it so that i can then collect multiple data to xlsx! :D
Some of the results have spaces in front of them, but thats fixed by adding .strip() at the end of print(name.text."strip()")

Comment: I also noticed that sometimes there are "triangles" (ascii code 9650), I modified the code in such a way as to remove spaces and "triangles"

Comment: Yes that works like a charm! I got inspired by your answer and replaced "Neues Angebot" too, so its nicer. Ill be working on getting more data and getting them to excel. Then probably model recognition script, so it will print out specs of the products on the go if they are missing based on the model and make :D. A bit ambitious maybe...

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` returns list of elements based on class you have to loop over it extract text for that `.get_text()`  or `.text` method can be used

```
data=soup.find_all("h3", class_="s-item__title")
products=[i.get_text(strip=True) for i in data]
```